# 2Checkut Checkout(accepting payments securely hosted by Verifone) integration with nodejs and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, 2checkout

does anyone knows how to integrate 2checkout in nodejs application. I have created and activated account, and I'm looking their documentation, and they have so much information but I can't find something clear.I need option to create subscriptions (recurring payments) from page hosted by them. I have found this documentation that describes checkout option, but there is no info about subscriptions, and also they need some info that can't be found on portal. I have contacted their support few days ago but they still didn't send any response.
https://verifone.cloud/docs/online-payments/checkout

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I found two options that are suitable for me. But I still can't generate merchant-token. https://verifone.cloud/docs/2checkout/Documentation/07Commerce/InLine-Checkout-Guide/InLine-Checkout-with-signature-generation
I'm doing everithing they described here but always same response "Authentication required". Is someone knows what is wrong? Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Token by using `2co-react`